# how to close 2 edges on a mesh

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, edges

I'm trying to merge these 2 edges together to close the leg when it tries to bend. I have tried selecting all and merging by distance but that didn't work. basically, I deleted this part of the leg a while ago by mistake and I'm trying to re-merge it with this newer version of the model from an older version and I can't get it to truly merge with the mesh.

I'm aware my weights are incomplete im going to fix that later

[here's the blend file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mmeSVjnfHTwYT_Bq7hghQVik03ITAubz?usp=sharing)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) two options:

- Just select the edges of the upper and lower part you want to connect and choose `Bridge Edge Loop` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) > *Bridge Edge Loop*).
- Since I can't see here exactly how your mesh is constructed, and the vertices may have (almost) the same position, you can also use `Merge by Distance`. If you choose this option, you may have to adjust the *Merge Distance* individually (<kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*). But first limit the area to which this should be applied by selecting the corresponding vertices.

Here you can find a more detailed description of  [Bridge Edge Loop](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html) and [Merge by Distance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#merge-by-distance).